# Get html from CDATA in xml

Tags: xml

I have a xml:

```html
<item>
      <title>This is title</title>
      <description>
          <![CDATA[<a href="#"><img src="http://sample.picture.jpg" ></a>
          </br>Something...blah blah blah]]>
      </description>
</item>
```

I want to use xsl to transform it to html, but in output html, the `<a>`  tag only display in text, not a picture. So, how to do that?

This is my xsl:

```html
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="/item">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to disable output escaping. Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: It worked in IE but not in Firefox. Have any way to do it in firefox?